# Can you please tell me what's wrong here? I'm trying to extract all the columns where all elements are same, but it's not working

Tags: r

my data set is called "train". I'm trying to extract the columns where every element is same. But R throws some error.

```
silly_var<-list()
for (i in 1:ncol(train)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(train)){
    if (train[1,i]!="NA"){
      if (train[j,i]=="NA") break 
      if (train[j,i]==train[1,i]) {
        if (j == nrow(train)) list.append(silly_var,colnames(train)[i])
      }else break
    }else
    {
       if (train[j,i]=="NA") {
         if (j==nrow(train)) list.append(silly_var,colnames(train)[i])
       }else break   
        }
  }
}
```

This is the error message I'm getting.

```
Error in if (train[j, i] == "NA") break : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: Can you share sample of your data along with expected output. Most probably there is a better way to do this without `for` loop.

Comment: What Ronak said, but maybe, for example, ```if (is.na(train[j, i]))``` form instead of ```== "NA"``` will help.

Comment: @RonakShah Please see the link for file below. There are around 100 columns with same values for all rows. I want to find an automatic way to extract those columns.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhgtVC_uTay-gZgiE6lTJur5FLuu8g?e=64lofd

Comment: @markhogue I tried that, but same error!

Comment: maybe you also have to check for ```is.null```

Comment: The one drive link gives me an error stating that the data is more than 5 MB. But do you need `Filter(function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1, df)` ?